# Can I use cucumber hooks with parameters

Tags: selenium, cucumber, hook, gherkin

Here is my example:

```
@smoke()
  Scenario: User Login Invalid scenario
    Given User is at the login page of the application
    When User login with the following username and password with data in excel at 
     "src/test/resources/excel/user1.xlsx"
```

And what I want to do is I want to pass my path as a hook parameter. Is this possible?

```
@smoke("src/test/resources/excel/user1.xlsx")
  Scenario: User Login Invalid scenario
    Given User is at the login page of the application
    When User login with the following username and password with data in excel at
```

If not, is there a way to import data and the before hook?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_hooks.htm.
You can use Before hook, or when setting driver, you can read your data and store it in global variable and then use it where you need.